# Regular expression to validate date in php

Tags: php, regex, datetime

Can anyone help me with the regular expression to find datime from string,format like

```
September 29th, 2010, 05:18 UTC
```

Comment: Regular expression format or _date_ format?

Comment: You also didn't specify what you want your backreferences to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how strict you want to validate.

```
^\w+\s+\w+,\s+\d+,\s+\d+:\d+\s+[\w:+-]*$
```

would work but wouldn't check if the dates are actually halfway valid. Date validation is notoriously hairy in regex, so I'd advise against that. Better try and parse the date and see if that throws an exception.

Answer (score 3):

There are about as many possible REGEXes as there are people writing them. This one should work, assuming the format is relatively strict.

```
^([\w]+) ([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^ ]+) (.*)$
```

If you're using PHP though, I'd rather just use `strtotime()` and work from there, it's a lot safer to guarantee you'll get a useful answer out of it. Just remember to config your default timezone.